# Why does react redux does not re render view for object states changes?

Tags: reactjs, redux

New to redux and react and I am not sure why views are not updated when objects in state is updated.

See jsbin: https://jsbin.com/wucutuhovu/1/edit?js,output

However it works for numbers: https://jsbin.com/kaloqanise/1/edit?js,output

Comment: In your example, you are mutating the state... Aren't you?

Comment: In first example you are mutating the object, the second one returns a new value

Answer (score 3):

Redux is doing a shallow comparison to the state. When you change `state.value`, the `state` still points to the same object.

Try changing `state.value += 1` to:

```
return Object.assign({}, state, {
    value: state.value + 1
});
```

Check out this JSBin: https://jsbin.com/cikinocudo/1/edit?js,output

Answer (score 1):

Avoid changing the state directly. I edited your first code with the objects. The second one is right but let's say we have different states in our app, so we have to initialize our states as an object. Check out the code [here](https://jsbin.com/wateyep/edit?js,console,output). Since you're using ES015, you should be able to grab some of those changes.

Codes Changed: I removed your JSON.stringify, created variable "INIT_STATE"